# How does windows interpret absolute path and relative path for a file?

Tags: ubuntu, path, javascript, sockets

**Disclaimer: I use Ubuntu, forgot many things about Windows.**

I am in a mind boggling problem, unable to decipher whether or not the way how Windows and Ubuntu manages files had anything to do with a javascript dependency called socket.io in particular.

I obtained the `failed to load resource net::err_file_not_found` error when I tried running my Nodejs web application on Windows, however, when I ran it on Ubuntu it went smoothly without a problem. I managed to fix it by changing the src from `/socket.io/socket.io.js` to  `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

Trying to figure out what is the difference in using socket.io dependency in my `.html` file.

In Ubuntu

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

In Windows

```
<script src="http://localhost:PORTNUMBER/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

In windows will it always require the path of a file to be specified or will windows always require you to use the absolute path? In ubuntu I see that the relative and absolute path are basically the same thing.

Comment: My suggestion?  Put everything back to fail mode.. Use the System Internals process monitor.  First, set a filter to include node.  As in "process contains node".  Make it fail.. look through the results.. if you can't find your answer (too much stuff!) Set a filter to look for socket.io.js and see what windows is attempting to find.  I use this a lot to debug problems just like this one.  At least you will get a clue about what it is doing under the hood.

Comment: Not very good with scripting but as far as Windows goes, src="file:///[path]/socket.io/socket.io.js"

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas whoa, this may actually be good. I don't know if my friend is willing to go through all that trouble even if we have solved the problem. I just really wanted to know how windows requires the path of a file.

Comment: @vssher does it always have to be like that? As in, does windows only accept the absolute pathing?

Comment: @m00ncake I find that if you are running an HTML in the same folder as your script (you can create one and place a shortcut on the desktop) it can start src="./<the rest>" meaning it's in the same folder or start in this folder.

Comment: No, windows doesn't require an absolute path any more than Linux does.  What you have to wonder is what is the "current working directory" at the time it tries to find the relative one.  That was why I made the suggestion.  Also, "./" is implied on windows.. you shouldn't need it.

Comment: @vssher oh, that's a good tip! Ill keep that in mind and pass it on.

Comment: The URL path is interpreted by the used web server and is therefore independent of the underlying operating system (except from file-system specialities like case insensitivity). I assume you are using different versions of node.js + libraries this is most likely the source of the differences.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas ahh! this is the answer I was looking for, I will absolutely go ahead and try it out. I am very curious as to why it is like that.

Comment: @Robert could be the different versions of node.js as the libraries were installed using my `.json` file. That is an interesting point you've made however.